# Unable to get cookie from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm having trouble getting a cookie back after logging in at a webservice. 
I'm able to connect, and get a bool back that login is succeeded (`infoservice.LoginToVault`).
But when I try to check if i'm connected (`infoservice.IsConnectedToVault`) I get a false back.

I figured out that the reason is because there's no cookie saved. So i tried using the cookiecontainer but something tells me i'm om the wrong track.. i guess i have to ask for the cookie at the time i login, but how?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
        InfoService infoservice = new InfoService(); // that's the webservice

        bool login = infoservice.LoginToVault("server", "vault", "user", "pass");
        bool check = infoservice.IsConnectedToVault();

        if (login == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Succesfully logged in!");
        }
        if (login == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login failed!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(infoservice.IsConnectedToVault());  // returns fallse..

        Uri siteUri = new Uri("http://ironman/CadacWebservice/InfoService.asmx");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteUri);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", cook.Domain);
            Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", cook.Path);
            Console.WriteLine("Port: {0}", cook.Port);
            Console.WriteLine("Secure: {0}", cook.Secure);

            Console.WriteLine("When issued: {0}", cook.TimeStamp);
            Console.WriteLine("Expires: {0} (expired? {1})",
                cook.Expires, cook.Expired);
            Console.WriteLine("Don't save: {0}", cook.Discard);
            Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", cook.Comment);
            Console.WriteLine("Uri for comments: {0}", cook.CommentUri);
            Console.WriteLine("Version: RFC {0}", cook.Version == 1 ? "2109" : "2965");

            Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", cook.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I was able to get my hands on some perl code, of which i know it works:
But now i need it in c#.

## Login:

```
$soap = SOAP::Lite->new( proxy => 'http://localhost/Webservice/InfoService.asmx');

$soap->on_action( sub {sprintf '%s%s', @_} );

$soap->default_ns('http://x/webservices/');

$soap->uri('http://x.com/webservices/');

$soap->proxy('http://localhost/Webservice/InfoService.asmx', keep_alive => 1, cookie_jar => 
HTTP::Cookies->new(ignore_discard => 1));

$soap->encodingStyle("");
```

## Login to webservice

```
my $som = $soap->call('LoginToVault',

                SOAP::Data->name('server')->value('server')->type(''),

                SOAP::Data->name('vault')->value('vault')->type(''),

                SOAP::Data->name('user')->value('user')->type(''),

                SOAP::Data->name('password')->value('pass')->type('')
);

my $result = $som->result, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gone through your code, I don't think so any mistake is there in ur code.  I have one question here
  1) Is that webservice has developed by you?
If no please test this webservice with the help of SoupUI. If yes please check that what the value u r returning from IsConnectedToVault method.